# Debugger/Ide for intel 8080 assembly programming

Tags: assembly, ide, debuggervisualizer

I took hcs12 microcontroller course in which we used code warrior for writing and debugging the assembly codes. Now, I'm taking operating systems course in which we use intel 8080 assembly language. Since I'm used to use compiler for high-level languages inherently I'm used to use debuggers supplied by compilers.

My problem is that with codewarrior I can easily check and see at which line my error occurs or my mistake happen. Is there any tool/compiler(preferred) you know for intel 8080 assembly language programming likewise codewarrior?

Answer (score 0):

Going backwards in time to an 8080 means you need to give up some of the "crutches" you've used, most notably a JTAG-based debugger.  The 8080 does not have JTAG support (which was developed DECADES after the 8080). Back then, when people wanted to do low-level debugging and verification, the go-to item was an in-circuit emulator (ICE).  This is basically an entire computer that simulates the 8080 at pin-level and runs your code.  It interfaces with another PC (back then it would have been DOS based) or it is part of a PC (again, DOS).

If you're looking to "work through" the code, might I recommend seeing if there is an 8080 simulator out there. If not, perhaps an 8085 or 8086 or 8088 simulator would assist you; just limit your registers and opcodes to the 8080 subset.